# ps, display pid and argv parameters without full command name?

Tags: linux, ps

I'm running under debian squeeze, and need to get processes list in very specific format.
Processes are started in following way:

```
/$script -- $param
```

Hereinafter I will call $script as "test.sh", so it would look like this:

```
/test.sh -- 99
```

I need to find all these processes pid list + their first argv parameter (there is only one argv parameter always):

$pid | $argv

I found that ps can output process list in user format with flag -o, for a moment my solution is: `ps -C script.sh -o pid,command=`, that returns the following:

```
6660 /bin/sh /var/www/test.sh -- 15
7012 /bin/sh /var/www/test.sh -- 18
7041 /bin/sh /var/www/test.sh -- 19
7541 /bin/sh /var/www/test.sh -- 16
7741 /bin/sh /var/www/test.shq -- 1
```

is it possible to show this output as following somehow?

```
6660 15
7012 18
7041 19
7541 16
7741 1
```

Answer (score 0):

a pipe to cut should do the trick:

```
ps -C script.sh -o pid,command= | cut -d' ' -f 1,5
```